# Nuances of meaning between "pas pour que" and "pour pas que"

Tags: sens, prépositions, négation, ordre-des-mots

In conversation with my colleague, I said with jocular sarcasm:

> Franchement, c'est trop lui demander de se rendre compte que si on l’en a mise au courant, c'est **pas pour** qu'elle nous bombarde de questions ?

Now I wonder how "pour pas que" (in the vein of "non pas que") is nuanced, compared to "pas pour que"?

> Franchement, c'est trop lui demander que de se rendre compte que si on l’en a mise au courant, c'est **pour pas** qu'elle nous bombarde de questions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les deux autres réponses sont justes lorsqu'elles affirment que les deux expressions ne sont pas réellement correctes, mais comme elles sont souvent utilisées à l'oral, il faut bien répondre à votre question :

> C'est pas pour qu'elle nous bombarde = Ce n'est pas pour qu'elle nous bombarde
>
> C'est pour pas qu'elle nous bombarde = C'est pour qu'elle ne nous bombarde pas.

Comment: Hi. So these two sentences actually have different meanings! The 1st version with "pas pour que": "si on l’en a mise au courant, ce n'est pas pour qu'elle nous bombarde de questions, ***mais pour une autre raison*** ". The 2nd version with "pour pas que": "si on l’en a mise au courant, c'est ***pour éviter*** qu'elle nous bombarde de questions".

Comment: The 1st interpretation is what I had in mind when I said this sentence.

Comment: Yes you are right, they have a different meaning.

Comment: Oui, et on peut entrevoir la distinction suivante: dans la première situation, la personne accusée a déjà commencé à bombarder de questions certaines personnes alors que dans la seconde, elle n'a pas nécessairement commencé mais des signes avant-coureurs l'annoncent.

Answer (score 1):

Even if in spoken French, you'll ear a lot of `pour pas que` but it is syntaxically incorrect.

The word `pas` express the negation in a sentence but placed after `pour` is not the correct way to put a sentence in a negative form, you should use the adverb `ne`

> Franchement, c'est trop lui demander que de se rendre compte que si on l’a mise au courant, c'est **pour qu'elle ne** nous bombarde **pas** de questions ?

Comment: Hi. On an incidental note, does it sound odd to use "en" in "si on l’***en*** a mise au courant"? I meant "en" as "mettre qn au courant ***de ...***".

Comment: I couldn't tell why but yes it sound very odd. I guess this is because `on l'a mise` already mentions what it is (`l'a`) you informed her, so there is no need to add another personal pronoun.

Comment: Hi. Actually, I meant it as "mettre qn au courant ***de qch***". "up to date ***about something***"

Comment: This is exactly the meaning of "on l'a mise au courant", _quelque chose_ being implicitely contained in `l'a`. Instead of using `l'en`, if you really want to be more explicit, add what it is you told her at the end `on l'a mise au courant de ...`

Answer (score 1):

"***c'est pas pour*** qu'elle nous bombarde de questions" est une contraction de 
"***ce n'est pas pour*** qu'elle nous bombarde de questions", qui est très utilisée à l'oral.

Cependant, il ne s'agit pas d'un langage formel : il vaut mieux l'éviter par écrit. Concernant "*c'est pour pas*", il s'agit pour moi d'une jolie faute de français !

Pour garder l'exemple précédent, on ne dirait pas "***ce n'est pour pas*** qu'elle nous bombarde de questions", il en va de même pour "***c'est pour pas*** ...".